# How, in a function, do I refer to a user-entered column name post join when a suffix has been appended by the join?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, reference

I am writing a function that is to work with user-supplied population data of any number of columns or rows. As part of the input, the user has to provide the data frame and the column number of the person `ID` variable, and the `Age` variable. So these columns can be any name, and at any column index in the data.

The purpose of what I am trying to do at the moment is semi-random observation pairing. The objective is:

- take the input data frame
- take a copy and make this the working data frame
- cut a sample of the required size (e.g. 5% of observations) from the working data frame into a new data frame
- delete those observations from the working data frame
- using a left join, match the sample data frame to the working data frame using age (some fiddling to ensure a 1-to-1 match rather than a 1-to-many match)
- remove those matched from the working data frame.

I'm stuck on the last part.

Let's call the input data frame `Input`, the working data frame `Working`, and the sample data frame `Sample`.  `Input` contains two columns, `ID` (which is column 1) and `Age` (column 2). But these could be any name and any column.

The column index for `ID` is passed in through `IDVariable`.

I have this in the function:

```
IDColName <- sym(names(Input[IDVariable]))
```

After I sampled the initial observations, I simply used the code below to remove those observations from the ahead of the joining:

```
 Working <- Input %>%
 filter(!({{IDColName}} %in% Sample[[IDColName]]))
```

But I can't work out how to amend this to take account of the join suffix. Here, foo represents the outcome of the left join:

```
foo <- data.frame(ID.x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7, 8, 9, 10), 
              Age = c(10, 5, 12, 14, 6, 7, 2, 8, 15, 6), 
              ID.y = c(21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30))
```

How do I update `Working` so that all the observations with an ID in `ID.y` are removed? Because I need to keep this data frame wide, doing a wide-to-long conversion isn't possible. Stripping the `.y` suffix isn't a solution for my problem, either.

I tried:

```
  Working <- Working %>%
  filter(!({{IDColName}} %in% Sample[[IDColName.y]]))
```

and got the error:

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x object 'IDColName.y' not found
ℹ Input `..1` is `!(ID %in% Sample[[IDColName.y]])`.
```

I will have outcomes where there is more than one left_join merge on age, so potentially the file could be 4 or more people wide. I need the solution to work with any join suffix that is appended.

Comment: I think you need to fix the column names in the first step, then the next steps you can work more precisely.

Comment: So there is no way to reference the column amended with the .y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think everything becomes easier if you rename your columns right off the bat. I didn't do any fiddling to avoid the one-to-many match here, but you could re-write that part:

```
library(tidyverse)
Input <- data.frame(name = c("Helen", "Thomas", "Rita", "Nicholas", "Greta", "Jake", "Clara"),
                    age = c(35, 60, 60, 23, 18, 18, 18),
                    other = rnorm(7))
IDvariable <- "name"
AgeVariable <- "age"

Input
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  name       age  other
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Helen       35 -0.326
2 Thomas      60  1.33 
3 Rita        60  1.27 
4 Nicholas    23  0.415
5 Greta       18 -1.54 
6 Jake        18 -0.929
7 Clara       18 -0.295


#-- Copy and make it the Working DF (with column name change for easier downstream)
FullWorking <-  Input %>%
    rename(ID = !! IDvariable, Age = !! AgeVariable) %>%
    select(ID, Age)

#-- Take sample (here 30% because my example is small)
set.seed(0)
Sample <- sample_frac(FullWorking, 0.3)

Sample
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  ID      Age
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Jake     18
2 Helen    35
```

Here's the part where you said you were stuck:

```
#-- Delete Sample Obs from Working
Working <- filter(FullWorking, ! ID %in% Sample$ID)

#-- Left join the sample data and get IDs to remove
ids2rem <- left_join(Working, Sample, by = "Age") %>%
    filter(!is.na(ID.y)) %>%
    pull(ID.x)

ids2rem
[1] "Greta" "Clara"

#-- Remove matched IDs from Working
FilteredWorking <- filter(Working, ! ID %in% ids2rem)

FilteredWorking
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  ID         Age
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 Thomas      60
2 Rita        60
3 Nicholas    23
```

Note that I used tibbles, but everything would work fine for data frames too.

Comment: I'll take a look ;)

Comment: i would be really really grateful

Comment: Thanks, it's making my life so much easier. No longer the {{}} constructions! :)